# R: ggplot2: how to separate labels in stat_summary

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, label

I try to plot labels above bars with the `stat_summary` function and a custom function that I wrote. There are three bars and each should be labeled with the letters a:c, respectively. However, instead of putting one label per bar, all three labels are placed on top of each other:

```
codes <- c ("a", "b", "c")

simple_y <- function(x) {
        return (data.frame (y = mean (x) + 1, label = codes))
        }


    ggplot (iris, mapping = aes (x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +
        geom_bar (stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean", fill = "blue", width = 0.7, colour = "black", size = 0.7) +
        stat_summary (fun.data = simple_y, geom = "text", size = 10)
```

[image]

I do understand why this is not working: each time the `simply_y`-function is recycled, it sees the whole `codes` - vector. However, I have no clue how to tell R to separate the three labels. Is it possible to tell R to subsequently use the n_th element of an input-vector when recycling a function?

Does anybody have a good hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider doing something like this:

```
labels <- 
  tibble(
    Species = factor(c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")),
    codes = c("a", "b", "c")
  )

iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarize(Mean = mean(Sepal.Length)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  left_join(labels, by = "Species") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = Mean)) +
  geom_col(fill = "blue", width = 0.7, color = "black", size = 0.7) +
  geom_text(aes(y = Mean + 0.3, label = codes), size = 6, show.legend = FALSE)
```

First, you can generate the data frame with means separately, avoiding the need for geom_bar and stat_summary. Then after joining the manual labels/codes to that summarized data frame, it's pretty straightforward to add them with geom_text.

[image]

Comment: This solution works and I like it, of course. However, for my purposes, I`d prefer a solution without the need to prepare the data before plotting.

Comment: @yenats It's probably the most crucial step in ggplot to get your data into the right shape for the purpose of your plot. It is very likely that you may need to reshape the same data in different ways for different plots - data shape is not stationary, and R makes it very easy to reshape. Actually - you're making your life much easier when you allow yourself to reshape your data :)

Comment: I came to the conclusion that indeed, reshaping the data seems to be best practice. Thank you for your support!